# Pythonic Referenced For Loop

Tags: python

I have a `for` loop as follows:

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5]
for i in a:
    i=6
```

What I would like is for every element of `a` to become `6`.

Now I know that this `for` loop won't do it, because I am merely changing the what `i` refers to.

I instead could write:

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5]
for i in len(range(a)):
    a[i]=6
```

But that doesn't seem very Pythonic. What are good ways of doing this sort of thing? Obviously, setting everything to `6` is contrived example and, in reality, I would be doing more complicated (and wonderful) things. Therefore, answers should be generalised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `for`-variable is always a simple value, not a reference; there is no way to know that it came from a list and thus write back to the list on changing.

The `len(a)` approach is the usual idiom, although you need `range` (or `xrange`) too:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
```

or, just as commonly, use the `enumerate` function to get indexes as well as values:

```
for i, v in enumerate(a):
    a[i]= v+1
```

a list comprehension might be a good alternative, eg:

```
a= [6 for v in a]
```

Comment: `The for-variable is always a simple value, not a reference`. It is always a reference.

Comment: it's like a reference - but numbers and strings are immutable, so they act like values

Comment: It's always a reference, period. It's just a copy of the reference the list uses.

Answer (score 1):

This would probably be a good use for [`map()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map) depending on what you're doing in real life.  For example:

```
a = map(lambda x: 6, a)
```

Comment: I really don't like how cluttered `map()` calls are vs the equivalent list comprehension `[6 for _ in a]`

Comment: I agree with @lunixbochs here. Map calls seem to be unwieldy and, despite being python, seem non-Pythonic. The enumerate function suggested by bobince, above, seems to be a nice solution.

Comment: I particularly like `map` when you've already got a function that does what you want, so you don't have to type the `lambda`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> a = [6] * len(a)
>>> a
[6, 6, 6, 6, 6]
```

Comment: Chris, this seems like a very specific use scenario. As the question states, the example used was purposely contrived. I was hoping for a more generalised answer.

Comment: Well, it's useful for a lot of things. Especially when you consider: a[2:] = [6] * len(a), or a[2::2] = [6] * len(a). In fact I used it the other day to implement a Sieve, I had a list of numbers, and then I used this expression to 'None' the numbers I no longer wanted.